# Git .gitignore not working with log files

Tags: git

I have git repository on `/var/www/html/projectx`. My goal is to tell git ignore two files  `/var/www/html/projectx/error.log` and `/var/www/html/projectx/requsets.log`.

I try add .gitignore file

```
[git@x]$ cd /var/www/html/projectx
[git@x projectx]$ nano .gitignore
```

.gitignore :

```
*~
*.log
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

.gitignore file won't affect files that are already tracked. You can remove them  with:

```
git rm --cached [file]
```

command.
If you want only to ignore it locally you may try make it ignored by:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged [file]
```

Or create explicit repository rules by editing `.git/info/exclude` file inside your repository. That's good way to ignore files that you generate but don't expect other users of repository to generate. Some details can be found [here](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/).

Answer (score 10):

If you have already added these files into your Git repository, `.gitignore` would not have any effect until you remove them. Try:

```
git rm --cached error.log requsets.log
```